# Automatic acceptance of the invitation to the meeting icalendar

Tags: email, outlook, icalendar, mime

Tell me please about the possibility of implementing an automatic acceptance of an invitation to an event in Outloock.

The task is for the participant of the event to receive a reminder of the type "Meeting" on the mail, which would be displayed in his calendar (Outlook mail client). In this case, the creation of an event on the calendar and its acceptance must occur automatically.

And if it possible, I need hiding the buttons "Accept", "In doubt", "Reject".

I form the markup of the following form:

```
X-Mru-BL: 0:0:2
X-Mru-NR: 1
X-Mru-OF: unknown (unknown)
To: user@example.ru
Subject: Вебинар "Test edu"
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: education@example.ru
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=004128EAC32576F1_="
X-Spam: Not detected
X-Mras: Ok

--=004128EAC32576F1_=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar;charset="utf-8";method=request

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 13.0 MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART:20180421T090000Z
DTEND:20180421T100000Z
DTSTAMP:20180420T115438Z
LOCATION:место проведения мероприятия - Online
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:
Ваша заявка на обучение согласована 
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=ru:Test edu
ORGANIZER;CN="Обучение":mailto:education@example.ru
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=FALSE;ORGANIZER;CN=Иванов Иван Иваныч:MAILTO:user@example.ru
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:5AD4A9AF457A1177
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN"><HTML><HEAD><META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 14.03.0227.000"><TITLE>Обучение &quot;</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><!-- Converted from text/rtf format --><P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="ru"></SPAN><SPAN LANG="ru-ru"></SPAN><SPAN LANG="ru"></SPAN></P><P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="ru"></SPAN><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=2 COLOR="#000000"></FONT><SPAN LANG="ru"><FONT FACE="Arial">Ваша заявка на обучение согласована</FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="ru"></SPAN><SPAN LANG="ru"><BR></SPAN><SPAN LANG="ru"></SPAN><SPAN LANG="ru"></SPAN></P></BODY></HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-P1D
REPEAT:2
DURATION:PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Test edu 21.04.2018 09:00:00
X-WR-ALARMUID:5AD4A9AF457A1176
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

--=004128EAC32576F1_=--
```

A letter of the following kind comes:

[image]

The question is: how to set a parameter or property in the code to remove the "Accept", "In doubt", "Reject" buttons from above and automatically confirm the event?

I tried to insert parameters PARTSTART = [ACCEPTED](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-2-12-participation-status.html), RSVP = FALSE, METHOD: PUBLISH (in this case the event is not added to the calendar, but requires the user to add it himself, that is, the option does not fit), the buttons still remain, and the event is not accepted in the calendar.

Comment: Sending a reminder message is good. I am just finding it difficult to see the point creating a system where the sender decides for the receiver in the name of automatic acceptance.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it? Or the logic and algorithm of the Outlook calendar will not allow this?

Answer (score -1):

No calandar client (be it Outlook or some other client) will let an invitation coming from some unknown organizer be added automatically to someone's calendar.

Imagine how your calendar would very rapidly become spammed with unsolicited invitations if that was possible ?

Finally, I see that your invitation contains a VALARM. Please be aware that alarms are also ignored for the same reason. See for example: [Sent email with iCal to outlook with valarm reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256584/sent-email-with-ical-to-outlook-with-valarm-reminder/33268200#33268200)