# Given ics VALARM properies are not appearing in Google Calendar or Outlook

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, outlook-calendar

I'm not able to find a solution or answer to this question because there appears to be a lot developers out there experiencing it.
I'm generating an ics file but the VALARMS are not setting reminders in google calendar or outlook 2007.
My ics file looks like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180719T094000Z
DTEND:20180719T104000Z
DTSTAMP:20180718T094001Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY
UID:bhanu@shinycreek.com
ORGANIZER;CN=bhanu@shinycreek.com:mailto:bhanu@shinycreek.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=shrikant@shinycreek.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:shrikant@shinycreek.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=johndoe_gemsessence@outlook.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:johndoe_gemsessence@outlook.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE;CN=bhanu@shinycreek.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:bhanu@shinycreek.com
CREATED:20180718T094001Z
DESCRIPTION:This is a meeting invitation for testing of invitation sent by email.
LAST-MODIFIED:20180718T094001Z
LOCATION:Indore, Madhya Pradesh
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Calender invitation for testing
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-P30M
DESCRIPTION:Event reminder
ACTION:EMAIL
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The google calender is ignoring my given VALARMS and displaying it's default `10 minutes before` under alarm section. 
I'm not getting any reason why the google and calender ignoring valarms.

Please help me if having any solution to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256584/sent-email-with-ical-to-outlook-with-valarm-reminder/33268200#33268200
This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sent email with iCal to outlook with valarm reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256584/sent-email-with-ical-to-outlook-with-valarm-reminder)