# iCal file doesn't import VALARM alerts into outlook as Internet Calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, icalendar, webcal

If I download my generated ICS file and import into Outlook as as a file (essentially just creating a snapshot) then the VALARM I have set works correctly.

What I want is a ical feed that will synchronize with the server.  So when I create an Internet Calendar (Add/Open Calendar -> From Internet) using my ICS file URL all the events are created correctly and synchronizing works, but the VALARM is ignored and not set

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:Appointment Calendar
METHOD:PUBLISH
SOURCE:ICAL-URL
X-WR-CALNAME:Appointments
X-WR-CALDESC:Calendar
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:84fbfa16-ab3a-4313-b98b-638da09a8a1c
DTSTAMP:20190107T190135Z
SUMMARY:My Event
DTSTART:20190109T183000Z
DTEND:20190109T184500Z
CATEGORIES:Red Category
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER:-PT15M
DESCRIPTION:Alert
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Am I doing something wrong or is VALARM not supported for internet calendars in outlook?  When I do this in Thunderbird w/ Lightning plug-in then it works great.  So I'm assuming there is some MS specific formatting I'm missing?

I am using Outlook 2016 for my testing.  I read that some people have success with logging into Office365 and importing calendars from the dashboard but this did not work for me either.  I have tried formatting my URL with both `http://` and `webcal://`

Comment: Have you validated your ics file?  http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com  gives: 
! CRLF should be used for newlines
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.1
! Invalid name [SOURCE]. Experimental properties must have the following prefix: X-
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.8.8.2

Comment: Other two validators seem happy though.

Comment: Seems outlook didnt use to support VALARM https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-calendar-import-with-remindersalarms/7d5f9690-7309-4a4d-8b4c-788c093b5b36, but then have also read somewhere that it loads them as reminders?  Maybe ask on outlook forums?

Comment: It appears that Google Calendar also ignores VALARM when subscribing via URL. Is there any workaround?